# SSH tunnel doesn't work in DataGrip

Tags: database, oracle, intellij-idea, ssh, datagrip

I have an Oracle database that is located on server_c and are only accessible if you are on server_b. So in order to connect to this Oracle database, I have to first log in to server_b via SSH, and type in the following command to connect to it.

```
sqlplus username/password@server_c:1571/service
```

I would like to connect to the Oracle database in DataGrip, first I typed in my username and password in the `SSH/SSL` tab.

[image: ssh tab]

Then I typed in the general database information.

[image]

I thought it would be fine, but when I clicked on the `Test Connection`, I got an error.

> Error: Connection to Oracle - @server_c failed. ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-20001: Server is not in the List of Valid Application Servers ORA-06512: at line 28

This error occurs if I try to connect to the database directly without logging in to server_b beforehand. In other words, I think DataGrip doesn't connect to the SSH tunnel first before connecting the database.

I'm not sure if I'm using `SSH/SSL` tab correctly in this way. So if you have any idea why it doesn't work or any solution to it, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using predefined oracle driver or manually created? Do you have warnings on configuration screen?

Comment: @kassak I'm using the predefined Oracle driver. In fact, I was pretty sure it worked because I connected successfully to another Oracle database. But for this Oracle database, I need to log in to another server to use it, that's why I need an SSH tunnel. But the tunnel didn't work, and I didn't see any warning on configuraiton screen, only an error showed up, I don't know why.

Comment: @Searene could you try to reproduce the issue since we reworked whole ssh subsystem?

Comment: Error messages starting from 20000 up to 20999 are custom, user-specified error messages. Oracle provides this range of error codes so applications can raise or display a custom application error. This is performed by using the PL/SQL raise_application_error function. So, for me it is clear that your database has a logon trigger preventing connections from unauthorised servers.  The error RECURSIVE SQL is telling you exactly which line in the logon trigger is responsible of raising the error.

Comment: So, it looks like SSH is working, you've got sqlnet.ora misconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error message:

> Error: Connection to Oracle - @server_c failed. ORA-00604: error
>   occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-20001: Server is not in the
>   List of Valid Application Servers ORA-06512: at line 28

Check with your DBA either of:

1. a `sqlnet.ora` valid node checking `tcp.validnode_checking` = ...

or more likely:

2. a login trigger that prevents "unknown servers" from logging in.

Comment: This contribution seems more appropriate as a comment rather than providing a definitive answer to the question asked. Consider using the comment function in the future ...

Comment: @Kris except that sharing that info in a comment would be less than ideal as well, this reads closer as an answer to me